# Ansible Transfer a file from window server A to window server B after running ansible playbook on server_ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

Good day. If I have linux ansible server (called server_ansible), then I would like to transfer a file from window server A to window server B.

How could I do?

Tried win_copy but not work.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem and resorted to a taks with a shell command using the `scp -r` option to transfer between two remote hosts.

```
scp -3 remote_user@ip_remote1:/path_to_source remote_user@remote2:/path_to_destination
```

You do however need to set up keys between the hosts.